# Django, how to create object in CreateView, manually

Tags: django

I have a `CreateView` which creating Model1 object. I need to create other object (in this view) which will has Model1 as a ForeignKey.

```
from .models import Model1, Model2

class Creating(CreateView):
    model = Model1
    fields = ["field"]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # how to create here something like this:
        # model2 = Model2.create(field_from_model2 = Model1_object_which_was_created_in_this_View?)
        return super(Upload, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `super()` is called for the `CreateView`, the object is saved as `self.object`. You can call `super()`, but **do not return the response yet**. You can then create the second object using `self.object`. Then finally, return the response.

```
class Creating(CreateView):
    model = Model1
    fields = ["field"]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(Creating, self).form_valid(form)
        object2 = Model2.objects.create(
            model1=self.object,
            # other fields
        )
        return response
```